# Unable to configure proguard for android

Tags: android, android-proguard

I'm trying to configure proguard for my application. Everything is working fine untill I enabled minifyEnabled in build file. after that is saying below error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar [E:\androidStudioProjects\name\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\componentClasses.jar] must be specified after an input jar, or it will be empty.
```

My gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.activity"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 29
        versionName "3.0.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
    compile project(':googlemapssdkm4b_lib')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.0'

}
```

my proguard-rules.pro file is

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
#-dontoptimize
#-dontpreverify

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
#
# Note that you cannot just include these flags in your own
# configuration file; if you are including this file, optimization
# will be turned off. You'll need to either edit this file, or
# duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
# file from your project's proguard.config path property.

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
 public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
}

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version. We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
```

Please help me on this..

Answer (score 0):

It took quite a while for me to figure it out but, as I had guessed, it was all about Proguard configuration.

I started to dig through the Warnings in the Console and realized that some of the References couldn't be found by Proguard. So adding them as -dontwarn to proguard configuration file solved the problem.

In my case, I had to ignore packages below;

```
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke**
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn com.nhaarman.**
-dontwarn se.emilsjolander.**
```

Comment: Hi Harshad. Thanks for replying . But above solution is not working for me